# Matrices times Kronecker Delta

Tags: linear-algebra

What would
$\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '}\Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta}\delta^{\lambda '}_{\gamma '}$ be equal to (where $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta)? Is it $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\beta}$? I don't quite get it, maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation convention is commutative and associative (since multiplication of scalars is, and you can interchange the order of summation); since the first factor doesn't involve $\gamma'$, you can compute this as

$$ \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '}\Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta}\delta^{\lambda '}_{\gamma '} = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '} \left( \Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta}\delta^{\lambda '}_{\gamma '} \right)
= \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '}\Lambda^{\lambda '}_{\beta}$$

Alternatively, the middle factor doesn't involve $\lambda'$ so

$$ \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '}\Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta}\delta^{\lambda '}_{\gamma '} 
= \Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta} \left( \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\lambda '}\delta^{\lambda '}_{\gamma '} \right)
= \Lambda^{\gamma '}_{\beta} \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\gamma '} $$

(note that both results are the same; notationally they only differ in the order the factors are written and the choice of dummy variable)